# How do I change the font size when printing from Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, printing, font-size

Sometimes I'd like to print my code and read it during lunch. In Eclipse I'm using 10pt Helvetica font, but printing at this size is a waste of paper I think. I changed to font size 6pt, and the print was perfect; fully readable and paper saving.

However, coding in 6pt font is very hard and stressing for my eyes, so I cannot keep the setting. Also, changing font size everytime I print is a pain.

Is there a way to keep 10pt for my editor AND have the printer run at 6pt, at the same time?

Comment: how about doing it using priniting preferences?

Comment: Do you mean the preferences under File->Print->Preferences? I can't find anything of relevance in there.

Comment: It doesn't appear that anyone has answered this question.  Am I wrong? Is it possible to keep 10pt in editor and print 6pt font.  I'm using Indigo 4.2 version for the Mac.Still doesn't appear possible.

Comment: This question would be so useful if there was a legit answer :( Seems like we are stuck going back and forth between font sizes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The mismatch of screen font size with printed font size is [supposed to be fixed](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=150870) in Eclipse version 3.7 (Indigo).  Perhaps you need a newer version of eclipse.

Comment: Is this not another issue, namely that there is a print scaling problem with GTK and not that the print font is the same as the screen font?

Answer (score 3):

I ended up changing the paper size to A5 and printing to PDF, then printing the PDF to A4.

Answer (score 2):

The best workaround I've found is to copy-and-paste the entire program into a text editor where one *can* tweak the page/font settings (I use gedit) and print from there. A pain, but less so than changing the font size within Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

This question was awhile back but I found a work-around to the original question posted. When I select File-Print then a Print menu options comes up (every print menu options is different depending on the OS. This is on a Macbook) I scaled the size of the printing down. Works great to read and more importantly, save trees!:-) [Scaling the printing of source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cmTJ.png)

Answer (score 2):

I tried scaling printout to 50-75% and it works for me also: Large font on screen but small font to fit all in less amount of paper

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:
Go to `preferences > appearance > colors and fonts` then select 'basic'.
In that drop down select 'text font'. Click 'edit' make your changes and print. When you're done you may want to change it back by clicking reset.

I found this information in two places
1: http://blog.alagad.com/2007/06/15/changing-the-font-size-in-eclipse/
2: http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/121/handouts/04a-eclipse-printing.pdf [PDF]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not what I'm looking for. (See the last sentence of the second paragraph in my post)

Comment: I am sorry I did not completely answer your question but this is the best solution I could come up with. I found quite a few bug reports to Eclipse about this very problem so I hope that gets fixed. Perhaps someone else has the solution?

Comment: Hi, where is preferences?  is this Project->properties in eclipse?  If so, I cant find appearance.  I also tried looking in Eclipse->Settings.  This is on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, Eclipse should have a 'Print font' setting.

This solution is late, but works so well, that I'm posting it anyway.

However, I have found a pretty good solution for me: **format for Ledger (11x17) but scale to Letter (8.5x11)**.  This is essentially 6 pt, which gets me 116 lines down, 140 cols across, in Portrait mode.

I like this so much, that for personal work, I have tweaked Eclipse to assume a 120 column print margin.  Here's how:

- Set Editing font to Consolas 10 pt. (This is my preference, however it doesn't make much difference, as you will see. (Window > Preferences > General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts > Basic > Text Font)
- Set Print margin at 120 characters. (Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Show print margin > Print margin column 120)
- Set code style formatter's line wrapping to 120 characters. (Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter > Active Profile > [your custom
  profile name] Edit > Line Wrapping > Maximum line width > 120).

The details of how you select the Paper size to format for, vary by printer.  For me, it is done from File > Print... > Preferences > Basic > Paper Size > Ledger.

Likewise, selecting page scaling is a printer preference.  For me, it is File > Print... > Preferences > Advanced > Scaling > Fit to Paper Size > Letter.

Answer (score 0):

Using Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) I still see this as a problem. I tried the scaling in the printer dialog as suggested by Allen and Eclipsed, and my Brother printer under Windows used just as much paper, using same page breaks, leaving white space at bottom of each page.

So do an experiment with a small selection before trying this. Your mileage may vary.

I'm almost ashamed to admit it, but, so that I could get colors, and preview before printing, I ended up pasting into Microsoft Word and printing from there.

Answer (score 0):

Just print to pdf with A3 paper size then print from your pdf reader. Works for me! Can get about 100 lines of code per sheet.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, and was given the following by a colleague.  The following should be entered on the command line:

- To check default font: `query default.print.font`
- To change font temporarily: `print.font "Courier New-10"`
- To change font permanently: `default.print.font "Courier New-8"`

Hope it helps

Comment: What "command line" do you mean? If command line arguments when starting eclipse is meant, this does not work with Luna on windows.